# A tricky question

Tags: number-theory

A prime $p$ is **lonely** in $a$ if $p$ divides $a$ but $p^2$ does not divide $a$. A number $a$ is **special** if it has no lonely primes. How to prove that there are infinitely many pairs of consecutive special numbers?
I tried for solving and got a pair as 8,9 but I do not know how to move further in this proof. Can anyone help?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee can you help in this proof?

Comment: Are $8$ and $9$ special numbers? How?

Comment: @hhsaffar if not can you explain it?

Comment: $2|8,4|8,3|9,9|9$

Comment: Inorder to be lonely 2^2 must not divide 8 hence I concluded it as not lonely.

Comment: This question was [posted again](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565649/special-numbers-and-primes) for some reason. Are you the one who posted again? If so, please know that duplicating is frowned upon and results in closures - just update your original question. If not, then where did this problem come from, that two people are asking it within hours of each other?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: One way to extend your example is to note that the Pell equation $x^2-8y^2=1$ has infinite solutions, say corresponding to $x_n+y_n\sqrt8 = (3+\sqrt8)^n$.

Comment: can you give me a set of special numbers?

Comment: $x^2$ and $8y^2$ are special. Search how to solve Pell equation.

Comment: I just gave you one for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$.  For e.g. $n=2$ gives $(17^2, 8\times 6^2)$, $n=3$ gives $(99^2, 8 \times 35^2)$, and so on.  Work it out, in fact you can get a recursion if you wish...

Comment: How come did you place 8 in Pell equation in this case?

Comment: We could use almost any special number that is not a square, but i chose to use your e.g. to extend it.  Try $27$ or $32$ instead of $8$, works fine.